# C# and VB.nET type

Tags: c#, vb.net

Does VB.NET have more types than C#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they are under the same .NET Framework, the only thing VB.NET has by default is a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.... namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Types in both languages refer to the same Intrinsic CTS Data Types. (CTS = [Common Type System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hf02550.aspx))

Comment: I think that out of all the answers, this is the perfect one! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

VB.NET lacked support for unsigned types back in the day, but now it's fixed. And since all these languages are CLR ones, the set of types is equivalent. VB.NET still has some weird old-school compatibility aliases (like `Date` and some others I can't remember) but these are just aliases to standard CLR types.

Comment: Not worth adding a full answer to include these points: VB.NET now also has the My Namespace, which can be seen as extra types, to some extent. VB.NET still can't handle true pointer types.

Answer (score 1):

Well the VB.NET has some stuff for backward compatibility with vb6 but you can access the moste of it from c# if you add a reference to the right assembly.